# OAGIS schema ignores <StreetName> node

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap, xsd-validation

Problem: When I am sending a request to Biztalk via a PHP `SoapClient`, I'm losing one node `<StreetName>`.

Biztalk validates our request by OAGIS schema.

For sending, I convert `XML` to `Array`, and send a request like an array, but when check my last soap request `$soapClient->__getLastRequest()`, I am losing nodes.

My request array:

```
 'Location' =>
    array(
        'Address' =>
            array(
                'StreetName' => 'StreetName',
                'CityName' => 'Zyrardow',
                'CountrySubDivisionCode' => 'PL',
                'CountryCode' => 'PL',
                'PostalCode' => '96-300',
            ),
    ),
```

In `$soapClient->__getLastRequest()` I'm losing node `<StreetName>`:

```
</ns1:Location>
    <ns1:Address>
        <ns1:CityName>MyCityName</ns1:CityName>
        <ns1:CountrySubDivisionCode>PL</ns1:CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <ns1:CountryCode>PL</ns1:CountryCode>
        <ns1:PostalCode>96-300</ns1:PostalCode>
    </ns1:Address>
</ns1:Location>
```

In OAGIS documentation node `<Address>` should contain this node
[OAGIS doc "Address"](http://www.datypic.com/sc/oagis941/e-ns1_Address.html)

In case, if I send in array :

```
<AddressLine>
```

or:

```
<LineOne>
<LineTwo>
<LineThree>
<LineFour>
<LineFive>
```

This node we are **NOT** losing!

Example of arrays and last request(`$soapClient->__getLastRequest()`):

```
'Location' =>array(
    'Address' =>
        array(
            'AddressLine' => 'AddressLine',
            'CityName' => 'Zyrardow',
            'CountrySubDivisionCode' => 'PL',
            'CountryCode' => 'PL',
            'PostalCode' => '96-300',
        ),
),
<ns1:Location>
    <ns1:Address>
        <ns1:AddressLine>AddressLine</ns1:AddressLine>
        <ns1:CityName>MYCHANGESHERE</ns1:CityName>
        <ns1:CountrySubDivisionCode>PL</ns1:CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <ns1:CountryCode>PL</ns1:CountryCode>
        <ns1:PostalCode>96-300</ns1:PostalCode>
    </ns1:Address>
<ns1:Location>
```

and:

```
'Location' =>array(
    'Address' =>
        array(
            'LineOne' => 'LineOne',
            'LineTwo' => 'LineTwo',
            'LineThree' => 'LineThree',
            'LineFour' => 'LineFour',
            'LineFive' => 'LineFive',
            'CityName' => 'Zyrardow',
            'CountrySubDivisionCode' => 'PL',
            'CountryCode' => 'PL',
            'PostalCode' => '96-300',
        ),
),
<ns1:Location>
    <ns1:Address>
        <ns1:LineOne>LineOne</ns1:LineOne>
        <ns1:LineTwo>LineTwo</ns1:LineTwo>
        <ns1:LineThree>LineThree</ns1:LineThree>
        <ns1:LineFour>LineFour</ns1:LineFour>
        <ns1:LineFive>LineFive</ns1:LineFive>
        <ns1:CityName>MYCHANGESHERE</ns1:CityName>
        <ns1:CountrySubDivisionCode>PL</ns1:CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <ns1:CountryCode>PL</ns1:CountryCode>
        <ns1:PostalCode>96-300</ns1:PostalCode>
    </ns1:Address>
<ns1:Location>
```

Additional info:

I found [documentation](http://www.visualschema.com/vs/oagis/SalesOrder/SalesOrder627.do), where it shows us that we need to choose what we will be sending. But in my case, some nodes are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

bdn,

OAGIS 9.4.1 the Address is defined as indicated in your link:
(Address Line or (Line One,Line Two,Line Three,Line Four,Line Five
) or (Building Number,Building Name,Street Name,Unit,Floor,
Post Office Box,Delivery Point Code))

If you choose to use AddressLine or LineOne you do NOT have the ability to use the StreetName by this definition.

The latest version OAGIS 10.1 does not have this limitation.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. But when I am sending  only `<StreetName>` without `AddressLine or LineOne` , I am losing `<StreetName>` node.

Answer (score 0):

bdn,

If you are using the choice of the sequence with the StreetName the XML Schema definition allows that by the definition. From the XML Schema Definition there is no way the xsd would remove content.

Mike